# I want to perform object detection using a model converted to tflite

Tags: python-3.x, tensorflow, tensorflow-lite

I just downloaded a model from TensorHub and converted it to TFlite.
I am trying to use the converted model for object detection, but it does not work at all.
Since it doesn't work, I'm wondering if I'm converting the model incorrectly to begin with.
Is there a problem with the following procedure?

1. download the model from TensorFlowHub
2. unzip the downloaded model (I used tar -zxvf model.tar.gz to unzip)
3. convert the model
   The following was used to convert the model

```
import tensorflow as tf

saved_model_dir = 'model_directory'
converter = tf.lite.TFLiteConverter.from_saved_model(saved_model_dir)

# In some cases the following code was also used
# converter.target_spec.supported_ops = [
# tf.lite.OpsSet.TFLITE_BUILTINS, # enable TensorFlow Lite ops.
# tf.lite.OpsSet.SELECT_TF_OPS # enable TensorFlow ops.
# ]

tflite_model = converter.convert()

# save the model.
with open('faster-rcnn-1024-test2.tflite', 'wb') as f: f.write(tflite_model)
  f.write(tflite_model)
```

The tflite file was output without any errors.
However, this file does not allow for good object detection (it does not work with an error in the first place).

Comment: Hi, can you give us the downloaded model from tensorhub to make tests ?

Comment: Thank you for your comment.
I used this model.
https://tfhub.dev/tensorflow/faster_rcnn/inception_resnet_v2_640x640/1
I downloaded it from here and converted it with the above source code.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to convert it first in frozen graph (.pb) before to convert it into .tflite.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).